# How to access fields of a containing class from a nested class

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get all fields from `SuperClass1` by reflection, when working with the type `SubClass1`?

Here's what I have so far:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuperClass1.SubClass1 class1 = new SuperClass1.SubClass1();
            PrintAllFields(class1);
        }

        public static void PrintAllFields(object obj)
        {
            var SuperClassType = obj.GetType();
            // How do I get the fields 'param1', 'param2', 'param3' from here?
            SuperClassType.GetFields();
        }
    }

    public class SuperClass1
    {
        public int param1;
        public int param2;
        public int param3;
        public class SubClass1
        {
            public int paramTest;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the declaring type.

You can have a look at the following link for more information: [MSDN, Declaring Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your code could be written as:

```
public static void PrintAllFields(object obj)
{
    var nestedClassType = obj.GetType();
    var declaringClassType = nestedClassType.DeclaringType;

    if (declaringClassType != null)
    {
        var fields = declaringClassType.GetFields();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check if there is actually a declaring type, because otherwise you `declaringClassType` will be null and you will end up with a `NullReferenceException`.